# Changing the value of nsmutable array without causing memory leak

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I have an `NSMutableArray` which contains `UIImageView` objects which are added to a scrollview.

```
[self.scrollView addSubview:UIImageView];
[self.array addObject:UIImageView];
```

I want to delete these objects and add the new ones after clicking on a button. I tried doing this by calling `removeAllObjects:` on the array but it is causing a crash.

```
for(int i=0;i<[self.array count];i++){
    [[self.array objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];
}
[self.array removeAllObjects];
```

Comment: Please post the code you are using please.

Comment: I assume addSubView:UIImageView is not exactly like that and you are using an instance of UIImageView instead? Where exactly do you think there is a leak?

Comment: This code is fine as you've presented it. The bug must be elsewhere in your code. You'll need to post more of the surrounding code so we can find the issue. It might be that you are double-releasing the items, or perhaps you've accidentally initialised your array as an immutable array instead of a mutable one. Do you have any yellow warnings in your code?

Comment: @JamesWebster Yes I am using an instance of UIImageView. Inorder to make the viewers understand i used UIImageView. I felt the leak is there in removeallobjects. When I am using removeallobjects for array it is crashing, but at the same time I have another mutablearray with same behaviour and it is possible to apply removeallobjects on it. I am not getting exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do like following code-

```
UIScrollView *scrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400)];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

array=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

UIImageView *img1=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 0, 100, 100)];
UIImageView *img2=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 100, 100, 100)];
UIImageView *img3=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 100, 100)];

[img1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"]];
[img2 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"]];
[img3 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"images.png"]];

[array addObject:img1];
[array addObject:img2];
[array addObject:img3];

for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++)    
    [scrollView addSubview:[array objectAtIndex:i]];
```

then for Remove all view and empty array Following code on buttonTouchUpInside()-

```
 for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++){    
    [[array objectAtIndex:i] removeFromSuperview];    
    [array removeObjectAtIndex:i];
}
```

Comment: That won't work because you are modifying the array as you loop through it. If you delete the items in the array while you step through, the array gets shorter so by the time you get to the end you are trying to delete items off the end of the array. Either count through the array backwards, or delete the 0th item each time.

Comment: @NickLockwood If i removed the removeallobjects code then the program is working fine. I am initializing the array and adding objects to it in one function, which is called in the viewdidload method. Please reply if you need any specific data. I tried using removeObjectAtIndex and I gave the condition [array count] >=0, but it was found that the program is getting crashed on second object's removal.

Comment: @Dipak Chaudhari What Nick told is true, the code for removing from view wont work as at some point the i value becomes greater than array count before removing all objects in the array. But I think a condition change may work.  If we are using [array count] >= 0. But it dint work out for me.

Comment: @NickLockwood Please see the code where I initialize the array 


 NSMutableArray *array_temp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; self.array= array_temp; [array_temp release]; array_temp = nil;